# Dose rpms that ended with .i386 can fit also for linux 64Bit

Tags: linux, 64-bit, redhat-enterprise-linux, 32-bit, rpm

we have linux redhat 7.3

```
[root@master install_zone]# uname -r
3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64
[root@master install_zone]# uname -a
Linux master.sys65.com 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 29 17:29:29 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

we want to install the anti virus from Symantec

```
Sav-12.0.3710-1000.i386
Savap-x64-12.0.3750-1000.x86_64
Savui-12.0.3710-1000.i386
```

can we install the rpm's:

```
Sav-12.0.3710-1000.i386
Savui-12.0.3710-1000.i386
```

inspite the linux is 64Bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, you can.  But any software that requires the 64 bit libraries will need them installed also.  You cannot mix and match 32-bit and 64-bit software and libraries, though they will happily coexist.  Unless you are trying to install 64-bit software on a 32-bit operating system or hardware.  I don't think that would work.  64-bit operating system + hardware equals goodness for both 32-bit and 64-bit software.